# Display Vertical legends for a continuous Measure in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

In Tableau Desktop, When coloring a graph by a Continuous Measure, the default color legend always appears in a horizontal Layout showing the range of colors from minimum value of the Measure to maximum value of the Measure (Left to Right):

[image]

However, I would like the legend layout to be a vertical one so that I can fit it into my Dashboard well. I tried the format options but could not find any to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to create another sheet with an aggregate of the profit on the rows. Hard to tell exactly how to do it without knowing your data, but you'll need to play around with adding dimensions as a detail on the marks card in order to get it to display as you'd like. Additionally, if you don't mind the legend not being continuous, you can change the aggregate of the profit to discrete.

Otherwise there is no standard way to format the legend to be vertical if it is continuous.